Error creating virtual host for rabbitmq in k8s (via minikube)
I am trying to run a rabbitmq service (in minikube) using the following k8s yamls:

configmap.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-configmap
data:
  rabbitmq.conf: |
    default_vhost = /
    listeners.tcp.default = 5672
    default_pass = admin
    default_user = root
    management.listener.port = 15672
    management.listener.ssl = false
    management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
  definitions.json: |
    {
      "vhost": {"name": "/"},
      "permissions": [
        {
          "user": "admin",
          "vhost": "/",
          "configure": ".*",
          "write": ".*",
          "read": ".*"
        }
      ],
      "queues": [
        {
          "name": "queue1",
          "vhost": "/",
          "durable": true,
          "auto_delete": false,
          "arguments": {
            "x-queue-type": "classic"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "queue2",
          "vhost": "/",
          "durable": true,
          "auto_delete": false,
          "arguments": {
            "x-queue-type": "classic"
          }
        }
      ]
    }


secrets.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-secret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  username: admin
  password: root


service.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  ports:
  - port: 5672
    name: amqp
  - port: 15672
    name: management


statefulset.yaml

# RabbitMQ StatefulSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  serviceName: rabbitmq
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: rabbitmq:4.0.3-management
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5672
          name: amqp
        - containerPort: 15672
          name: management
        env:
        - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: rabbitmq-secret
              key: username
        - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: rabbitmq-secret
              key: password
        - name: RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE
          value: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
        volumeMounts:
        - name: rabbitmq-data
          mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq
        - name: rabbitmq-definitions
          mountPath: /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
          subPath: definitions.json
        - name: rabbitmq-config
          mountPath: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
          subPath: rabbitmq.conf
      volumes:
      - name: rabbitmq-definitions
        configMap:
          name: rabbitmq-configmap
      - name: rabbitmq-config
        configMap:
          name: rabbitmq-configmap
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: rabbitmq-data
    spec:
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi

I get the following error from the logs:
[error] <0.254.0> 
[error] <0.254.0>     rabbit_boot_steps:-run_step/2-lc$^0/1-0-/2, line 55
[error] <0.254.0>     rabbit_boot_steps:run_step/2, line 58
[error] <0.254.0>     rabbit_boot_steps:-run_boot_steps/1-lc$^0/1-0-/1, line 22
[error] <0.254.0>     rabbit_boot_steps:run_boot_steps/1, line 23
[error] <0.254.0>     rabbit:start/2, line 990
[error] <0.254.0>     application_master:start_it_old/4, line 293
[error] <0.254.0> 
[error] <0.253.0>   crasher:
[error] <0.253.0>     initial call: application_master:init/4
[error] <0.253.0>     pid: <0.253.0>
[error] <0.253.0>     registered_name: []
[error] <0.253.0>     exception exit: {{error,<<"Please create virtual host \"/\" prior to importing definitions.">>},
Runtime terminating during boot (terminating)
[error] <0.253.0>                      {rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}
[error] <0.253.0>       in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 142)

AFAIK I am creating the vhost that it mentions to be missing. Or am  I doing something wrong but I am too oblivious to see it?
I was running fine until yesterday, and there hasn't been any changes since. I have looked at similar questions in SO but none of them seem to be relevant to what I am doing, or the solution isn't applicable
